# concat pdf documents adobe professional

Tags: pdf, adobe, concatenation

hi
how to concat PDF documents in Adobe Professional via commandline or SDK.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is the use of "Adobe Professional" a must?
You can do this with ghostscript easily:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=joined.pdf f1.pdf f2.pdf
```

Comment: Yes kind of. the quality of the generated PDF is very important.

Comment: Instead of trying to convince You that word "professional" doesn't always mean "better quality" I'll tell that You always can check Yourself; gs is free.

Comment: Believe me we have to do what the client says.

Comment: @barti_ddu Dude. You just saved my life.